# VSTS build fails because it tries to build a UWP project for AnyCPU

Tags: msbuild, win-universal-app, uwp, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a UWP project on VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services). When built the following error message occurs and the build fails.

```
The project "Dummy.Win" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
```

The solution consists of 3 projects.

- `Dummy.Win` which is the UWP project based on 10586
- `Dummy.Core` which is a PCL
- `Dummy.Test` which is a test project

`Dummy.Win` references `Dummy.Core`.

The following command line shows how `msbuild` is called (added some line breaks):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" 
  "C:\a\1\s\Dummy.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false 
  /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\a\1\s\Dummy.sln.log" 
  /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.99.0\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.99.0\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
  /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM" 
  /p:AppxPackageDir="C:\a\1\b\AppxPackages\\" 
  /p:AppxBundle=Always 
  /p:configuration="Release" 
  /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
```

The question is: Why is `msbuild` trying to build the UWP project for AnyCPU? Running this command locally does not show this error (still doesn't create a .appxupload file but that's another issue)

Comment: Hello. First question -  did you check "Build" option in the configuration manager for this project?

Comment: Yes, checked that multiple times. Building the solution via VS works. Also via msbuild on cmd-line works (More or less as I don't get a .appxupload file. But as I said, this is another issue)

Answer (score 1):

Open the .SLN solution file with a text editor and find the section SolutionConfigurationPlatforms as shown below. Delete the lines having "Any CPU"

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|ARM = Debug|ARM
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|ARM = Release|ARM
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
```

Answer (score 0):

This may caused by the build platform of other projects in your solution. For example, the "Dummy.Test" project. If it is a general test project instead of a universal windows test project. Then the build platform for it will be "Any CPU" by default. And a build settings with "Release" configuration and "Any CPU" platform will be added to your solution.

Right click on your solution from VS and select "Configuration Manager...", select "Release" for "Active solution configuration:" and "Any CPU" for "Active solution platform:", and then check if the "Build" option of "Dummy.Win" project is checked. If not, check the option and check in the changes and then try the build again.

Comment: I removed the test project and it didn't worked. I then readded the test project just to double check and since then it is working? I probably played too much w/ some settings so I'm not sure why it works all of a sudden. However, I still don't understand the difference between VS  build and VSTS build. Both are using msbuild probably w/ the same arguments. So why are they behaving so different? (anyway, different discussion)